# Scaling a div but keeping it contained within a certain width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to scale a div that contains some annotations and a background image, but when I do, some of the annotation controls are being overlapped. What I'd like to do have my div in some type of container that has a width and height constraint on it so when I scale my content by 2, a vertical/horizontal scroll bar is present and my controls will not be overlapped.

Here is before the div containing the image and annotations is scaled:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXXuZ.png

and after scaling:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr3Mq.png

JQuery Methods:

```
 $.fn.annotateImage.zoomImageIn = function(){
    $('.image-annotate-canvas').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(1.25)');
  }

 $.fn.annotateImage.zoomImageOut = function(){
     $('.image-annotate-canvas').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(1)');
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="container" class="container">
        <img id="toAnnotate" src="images/exam_scan.jpg" alt="Exam 1" style="width:500px;    height:700px;" />       
 </div>
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. You would need to scale both the position and dimensions of the annotation. Show some code.

Comment: The JS Library I am using to annotate the image is:
https://github.com/flipbit/jquery-image-annotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following css on the container to add  scroll bars when the content expands past the fixed size.

```
"overflow:auto"
```

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/sn6wyv49/5/

Click the button to change the image size.